# How to get option key from a select using Vue.js with Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using Vue.js 2 with Laravel 7.
I must do an insert to the db through a form submit but I am unable to get the option key of a select.

This is the select:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="room">Room:</label>
            <select v-model="room" class="form-control" id="room">
                <option v-for="room in rooms" :key="room.id">
                    {{ room.name }}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

This is the script:

```
export default {
    props: ['hours'],
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.');
        this.loadUsers();
        this.loadRooms();
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            users: [],
            rooms: [],
            room: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onCreate: function (args) { 
            let value = this.$refs.textareaObj.value; 
            alert(value); 
        },
        loadUsers: function() {
            axios.get('api/users')
            .then((response) => {
                this.users = response.data.data;
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                alert('noviva');
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
        loadRooms: function() {
            axios.get('api/rooms')
            .then((response) => {
                this.rooms = response.data.data;
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                alert('noviva');
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
        insertMeeting: function() {
            alert(this.room);
        }
    }
}
```

In the insert, I need to get the id of the room but I don't know how to do that. The function `insertMeeting` should alert that id. By the way, in that alert appears only the option value (`room.name`) but I am interested in the option key (`room.id`).
Can help?

Comment: We can't reproduce what you see. What does `axios.get('api/rooms')` resolves to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the `option`'s `value` to its `room`'s `id`, which will be stored in the `room` property bound to its parent, `select`, via `v-modal`:

```html
<select v-model="room" class="form-control" id="room">
  <option v-for="room in rooms" :value="room.id" :key="room.id">
    {{ room.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

[Demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-cloud-l4ksq?file=/src/App.vue:75-256)